# Changing the UI in the onComplete method of the OnCompleteListener for a Task

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a Cloud Firestore database to populate a RecyclerView in an Android app. I'm getting the data by using a Task in the onAttach method of a Fragment. I need to be able to update the UI, the RecyclerView with data from the Cloud Firestore.

I populated the RecyclerView with dummy data in the onAttach method of the Fragment and that worked, but when I put the same loop that inserts dummy data in the onComplete method of a OnCompleteListener that's used in the Task that pulls data from the Cloud Firestore, the RecyclerView doesn't update and the list stays blank. I need to do it there to eventually insert data from the Cloud Firestore.

Within the Fragment. The data coming back from the Firestore database is correct and I see all of the Log statements in the onComplete method in the Logcat.

ChatListFragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat_list, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }
        chatRecyclerViewAdapter = new ChatRecyclerViewAdapter(ChatList.ITEMS, mListener);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(chatRecyclerViewAdapter);
    }
    return view;
}

...

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "activity attached, creating Firestore instance");

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    //Worked, but doesn't in OnCompleteListener
    /*for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        ChatList.addItem(ChatList.createDummyItem(i));
    }*/

    Task<QuerySnapshot> task = db.collection("chats").get();
    task.addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ID = " + document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    ChatListMessage chatListMessage = document.toObject(ChatListMessage.class);

                    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "adding message");
                        ChatList.addItem(ChatList.createDummyItem(i));
                    }
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ChatListMessage members " + chatListMessage.getLastMessage());
                }
            } else {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Within the ChatList class

```
public static void addItem(ChatListItem item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
    ITEM_MAP.put(item.userId, item);
}

public static ChatListItem createDummyItem(int position) {
    return new ChatListItem(String.valueOf(position), R.drawable.profile_circle, makeDetails(position),
                    new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
}

public static class ChatListItem {
    public final String userId;
    public final int pictureUrl;
    public final String lastMessage;
    public final Timestamp timeStamp;

    public ChatListItem(String userId, int pictureUrl, String details, Timestamp timeStamp) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.pictureUrl = pictureUrl;
        this.lastMessage = details;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return userId;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public String getTLastMessage() {
        return lastMessage;
    }
}
```

The custom RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class ChatRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<ChatListItem> mValues;
    private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public ChatRecyclerViewAdapter(List<ChatListItem> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
        mValues = items;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.contactImageView.setImageResource(mValues.get(position).pictureUrl);
        holder.contactImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).lastMessage);

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (null != mListener) {
                    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                    mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final ImageView contactImageView;
        public final TextView messageMembersTextView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public final TextView timestampView;
        public ChatListItem mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            messageMembersTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.message_members);
            contactImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.contact_imageView);
            mContentView = view.findViewById(R.id.content_textView);
            timestampView = view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp_textView);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the UI to be updated with the onComplete method of the OnCompleteListener?

Comment: There's not enough information here.  Where and how is ChatList consumed?  Bear in mind that the Firestore listener is asynchronous, and ChatList will not be populated before `onAttach` returns (unlike your test code, where it is fully populated before it returns).  Is the thing consuming ChatList getting no data, because the data hasn't been populated yet?

Comment: @DougStevenson I added some more details to the post. The ChatList has a ChatListItem that's being consumed by a custom RecyclerViewAdapter. I see the "adding message" log in the logcat when the onComplete method is run later so wouldn't the data get populated at that time? Is the reason it isn't because it's not running on the UI thread?

Comment: Everything is running on the UI thread, but not in the order that it appears in the code.  That's what I mean by asynchronous.  What does the list of chat items contain when it's received by the adapter?

Comment: Looks like I forgot to include notifyDataSetChanged() after adding bet ChatList items. I added this and it's working. Thanks @DougStevenson for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For this, chatRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() needs to be called in the onComplete method of the OnCompleteListener. I forgot to do this outside of the listener since it looks like the list items are pulled in after the onAttach method is called.